# Defaulted move assignment cannot be explicitly noexcept if a member has a non-trivial noexcept assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator

This code fails to compile with gcc 4.8.2 (-std=c++11) but compiles with clang 3.4 (trunk) (-std=c++11):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct X {
  X& operator=(X&&) noexcept = default;
  // adding noexcept this leads to an error in gcc, but works in clang:
  // function ‘X& X::operator=(X&&)’ defaulted on its first
  // declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the
  // implicit declaration ‘X& X::operator=(X&&)’

  std::vector<char> m;
};

// this assert holds, even without noexcept
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<X>::value, 
              "type-specification violation");

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

The `static_assert` is the interesting part on gcc: the defaulted move assignment will be `noexcept`, but I cannot declare it that way.

A variant not involving `vector` is:

```
template<bool b>
struct F {
  F& operator=(F&&) noexcept(b) {return *this;}
};

struct X {
  X& operator=(X&&) noexcept = default;
  F<true> f;
};
```

What is the expected behavior here? Intuitively clang seems correct.

Comment: I didn't realize that GCC already implementes the "nothrow" type traits...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53903), [that](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1351) and [this](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2165) may be related.

Comment: @remyable The first bug seems to be reminiscent of mine, but if you use my minimal example and replace `noexcept(b)` with just `true` I do not get an error. The second report talks about `throw-expressions` I don't see how that is related. The third report seems to be a library bug, but I'm not involving the library here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example not involving `vector` should compile.  clang is correct on this one.

The example involving `vector` may or may not compile, depending on whether the std::lib vendor has marked the move assignment operator of `vector` as `noexcept` or not.  The standard does not require this signature to be `noexcept`.  The standard does allow vendors to add `noexcept` if the function will never throw.

[libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) marks the `vector` move assignment operator as `noexcept` if `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is true and `is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value` is true (as a conforming extension).  Both of these are true in the libc++ implementation for `std::allocator<T>`.

**Update**

Pulling out the language lawyer hat on request.

`<disclaimer>`

I'm poking around in the half of the standard that is not my area of expertise.

`</disclaimer>`

> Could you be more explicit on why the example should compile?

All quotes are from the latest C++1y working draft, [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).

---

This specifies that an exception-specification is allowed on an explicitly defaulted special member:

8.4.2 **Explicitly-defaulted functions** [dcl.fct.def.default]/p2

> 2 An explicitly-defaulted function may be declared `constexpr` only if
>   it would have been implicitly declared as `constexpr`, and may have an
>   explicit *exception-specification* only if it is compatible (15.4)
>   with the *exception-specification* on the implicit declaration.

---

This defines "compatible exception-specifications:"

15.4 **Exception specifications** [except.spec]/p3

> 3 Two *exception-specifications* are *compatible* if:
>
> - both are non-throwing (see below), regardless of their form,
> - both have the form `noexcept`(*constant-expression*) and the *constant-expressions* are equivalent, or
> - both are *dynamic-exception-specifications* that have the same set of adjusted types.

Bullet 2 covers your case.

---

This explains why the implicitly declared special member is `noexcept` in your example:

15.4 **Exception specifications** [except.spec]/p14

> 14 An inheriting constructor (12.9) and an implicitly declared special
>   member function (Clause 12) have an *exception-specification*. If f is
>   an inheriting constructor or an implicitly declared default
>   constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy
>   assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   *exception-specification* specifies the *type-id* `T` if and only if `T` is allowed by the *exception-specification* of a function directly
>   invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` allows all exceptions if any
>   function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` has the
>   *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

Because every function invoked by an implicitly declared `X& operator=(X&&)` allows no exceptions (i.e. the move assignment operator of `F<true>`), this special member is `noexcept(true)`.

---

I *believe* that nails it down.

Comment: libstdc++ shipped with gcc 4.8.2 has the same `noexcept` operator as libc++, so this example should compile as well, making this a gcc bug. I didn't know this was an extension, but assumed this was required by later drafts.

Comment: Could you be more explicit on why the example should compile? The language concerning noexcept and defaulted special members is really hard and not very clear to me, especially since there is a bunch of DRs and resolutions for it. Than I can mark this as accepted. My example using `vector` was ill chosen, because it adds another dimension to the question which is not directly related to the real problem.

Comment: The only thing that seems complicated here is `equivalent constant-expressions` for the `noexcept(constant-expression)`: How does that work with templates? Do they have to evaluate to the same value in a particular instantiation or do they need to be the same for every possible instantiation? But that should possibly be its own question. Thanks for making this clear.

Comment: @pmr:  Evaluate to the same for a particular instantiation.  Each instantiation is a separate type, and can have different compile time properties.